# USART and ATmega RX Problem

Tags: uart, atmega, rxd

I'm trying to understand how USART of ATmega works. I read some pages and I've picked information about it. To test functionality I've written this code:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000
#define BAUD_RATE_115200_BPS  8

#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Transmit(void);

unsigned char data[] = "Data transmitted...";

int main()
{
    unsigned int ubrr = BAUD_RATE_115200_BPS;

    UBRR0H = (uint8_t)(ubrr >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (uint8_t)(ubrr);
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << USBS0) | (3 << UCSZ00);

    DDRB = 0b11111111;

    Transmit();

    while(1)
    {
        while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << RXC0)));

        //data[0] = UDR0;
        //data[1] = 0;

        sprintf(data, "%d", UDR0);

        Transmit();

        switch(UDR0)
        {
            case 'A':
                Transmit();
                PORTB = 0b11111111;
                _delay_ms(2000);
                PORTB = 0b00000000;
                break;

            case 'B':   
                PORTB = 0b11111111;
                _delay_ms(500);
                PORTB = 0b00000000;
                break;          

            default  :
                break;

        }
    }
}


void Transmit(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    while(data[i] != 0)
    {
        while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
        UDR0 = data[i]; 
        i++;
    }

    _delay_ms(100);
}
```

I can send data without problem, but I can't receive correct data. If I send "A", I receive ASCII code 161 or 225 and with "B", 162 or 226. I don't understand where the problem is.

For tests I'm using Arduino Uno (ATmega328P 16MHz).

Comment: I find it odd that TX works and RX doesn't. Neither should work, as the baud rate your code selects is 111111 BPS, which is almost at the edge of operating tolerance to communicate with a device set to 115200 BPS. Change to slower speed that can be achieved more accurately, like 38400 BPS.

Comment: I tried to 38400 and the problem is the same.
The differences are that, when i send "A" I receive always 97 rather than 161 or 225 and 98 for "B".
The receiveing data seem to be more stable but in any case wrong.
Could it be the arduino bootloader that creates problems?

Comment: Are you sending capital or small letters?

Comment: Capital letters "A" = ASCII 65

Comment: That is weird. 97 is non-capital 'a'. and 98 is non-capital 'b'. What terminal you are using? Are you absolutely sure you have caps lock at correct state, and/or you use shift button correctly to send capital letters? What is the baud rate divisor now? Is the 16 MHz clock source a crystal or ceramic resonator or something else, and do you know it's tolerance? What if you simply press SHIFT-A ?

Comment: Aaaaaargh!!!! You're right.
I tried with shift key pressed and released, but without any result.
Now I changed terminal program and it work.
I'm stupid, because I haven't think to verify 97 to which character corresponding.
If I did, I would have understood immediately the problem :(
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The baud rate is on the edge of accepted tolerance, so change to 38400 BPS.
Try different terminal program which can send capital and non-capital letters properly.